# Lagging videostream when using holographic remoting that processes a GoPro videostream

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, live-streaming, hololens

**Background:**
I got a unity project that (within a script) calls C++ methods from a shared library. The methods allow to receive a live videostream from a GoPro Hero4 via WiFi network. Whenever a frame is received unity will update a SpriteRenderer texture to display the image within the play mode. Simulataneously, the play mode is streamed to a HoloLens2 via holographic remoting using the mixed reality toolkit.

**The issue:**
Within the play mode the textures get updated with quite large delay of about 8 seconds. Whenever the holographic remoting is deactivated the stream is shown fluently within the play mode!

C#:

```
...

[RequireComponent(typeof(SpriteRenderer))]
public class SpriteMaker : MonoBehaviour
{
    SpriteRenderer rend;

    [DllImport("NDVIstreamer_dll2")]
    private static extern void NDVIStreamer(IntPtr data, int width, int height);

    [DllImport("NDVIstreamer_dll2")]
    private static extern void Init();

    private Texture2D tex;
    private Color32[] pixel32;

    private GCHandle pixelHandle;
    private IntPtr pixelPtr;
    
    void Start()
    {
        rend = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

        tex = new Texture2D(640, 240, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);
        pixel32 = tex.GetPixels32();
        //Pin pixel32 array
        pixelHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(pixel32, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        //Get the pinned address
        pixelPtr = pixelHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject();

        Init();

        MatToTexture2D();

        //create a sprite from that texture
        Sprite newSprite = Sprite.Create(tex, new Rect(0, 0, tex.width, tex.height), Vector2.one * 0.5f);
        rend.sprite = newSprite;

        pixelHandle.Free();
    }

    void MatToTexture2D()
    {
        NDVIStreamer(pixelPtr, tex.width, tex.height);

        tex.SetPixels32(pixel32);
        tex.Apply();
    }
}
```

C++:

```
...

extern "C" void __declspec(dllexport) Init()
{
    _capture.open(0);
}

extern "C" void __declspec(dllexport) NDVIStreamer(unsigned char* data, int width, int height)
{
    Mat _currentFrame(height, width, CV_8UC4, data);

    _capture >> _currentFrame;

    //reformatting the frame so it is unity compatible

    memcpy(data, _currentFrame.data, _currentFrame.total() * _currentFrame.elemSize());

    
}
```

The settings of holografic remoting look like this:
[image]

Comment: holographic remoting in general has some laggs and is only supposed to be used for quick testing/prototyping/debugging

Comment: when i remote webcam frames that pass the same algorithm i have almost no lag. it would be interesting whether one has ever modified the holographic remoting functionality to adjust for example the buffer size !

Comment: the thing is that I am actually using holographic remoting for prototyping..it is an application for which the implementation as a deployed app on the hololens would afford way more (take more time to debug).